# Writing a correct Comparator

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to write a `Comparator` to compare two objects based on a certain category field that they contain. Being new to writing custom `Comparator`s, I am unable to sort them properly. My code is as follows:

```
@Override
public int compare(ParseObject event1, ParseObject event2) 
{
    String cat1 = event1.getString(Fields.CATEGORY);
    String cat2 = event2.getString(Fields.CATEGORY);
    Date date1 = event1.getDate(Fields.EVENT_DATE);
    Date date2 = event1.getDate(Fields.EVENT_DATE);
    if(cat1.equals(category) && !cat2.equals(category))
    {
        // If event1 matches the category and event2 doesnt
        // event1 is greater
        Log.v("COMPARING", cat1 + " with " + cat2 + ", " + cat1 + " is greater ");
        return 1;
    }
    else if(!cat1.equals(category) && cat2.equals(category))
    {
        // If event1 doesnt match the category and event2 does
        // event1 is lesser
        Log.v("COMPARING", cat1 + " with " + cat2 + ", " + cat1 + " is lesser ");
        return -1;
    }
    else if(cat1.equals(category) && cat2.equals(category))
    {
        // If both belong to the same category
        Log.v("COMPARING", cat1 + " with " + cat2 + ", " + cat1 + " is equal ");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // Else they both do not belong to the category
        // return 0
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have used a simple two-bit binary table 00,01,10,11 to come up with the conditions. Is this the right way to write the comparator? Have I made any mistake by making the conditions too convoluted?

**Case1 Looking for "Workshop" Events:** (Workshop events are pushed down the list)

Events that have "Workshop" category are greater.

```
07-23 16:08:47.399: V/COMPARING(17806): Workshops
07-23 16:08:47.399: V/COMPARING(17806): Workshops with Workshops, Workshops is equal 
07-23 16:08:47.399: V/COMPARING(17806): Fests  with Workshops, Fests  is lesser 
07-23 16:08:47.399: V/COMPARING(17806): Fests  with Workshops, Fests  is lesser 
07-23 16:08:47.399: V/COMPARING(17806): Fests  with Workshops, Fests  is lesser 
07-23 16:08:47.399: V/COMPARING(17806): Workshops with Workshops, Workshops is equal 
07-23 16:08:47.399: V/COMPARING(17806): Workshops with Workshops, Workshops is equal
```

**Case2 Looking for "Fest" Events:"** (No comparison at all)

```
07-23 16:10:13.639: V/COMPARING(17806): Fests
```

I am using `Collections.sort(listOfEvents,myComparator)`.

Comment: Where does `category` come from ? What is the final order you expect ? Why aren't you just comparing `cat1` with `cat2` ?

Comment: This doesn't look incorrect, although it's unusual - most people probably wouldn't use a comparator to find items (only to sort them, e.g. when sorting alphabetically by category)

Comment: @FlorentBayle `category` is a field in the `ParseObject` that comes from the server. I double-checked to see if there were any mistakes in teh data from the server. There werent.. The order that I am expecting is that any event which matches a given category is moved to the start of the list. `cat1` with `cat2`? How so?

Comment: @immibis Have a different logic that I can use? :)

Comment: @LittleChild typical code would be `List<ParseObject> result = new ArrayList<>(); for(ParseObject object : list) if(object.getCategory().equals(category)) result.add(object);` (or something shorter using Java 8 lambdas; Java 8 doesn't seem to be widely installed yet so I'm avoiding it).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. But, what about making it a bit more concise:

```
String cat1 = event1.getString(Fields.CATEGORY);
String cat2 = event2.getString(Fields.CATEGORY);
int c1 = cat1.equals(category) ? 1 : 0;
int c2 = cat2.equals(category) ? 1 : 0;
return c1 - c2;
```

This will do exactly what your method does, but it is shorter, easier to read (IMHO) and more efficient, as it only invokes `equals` twice.

Comment: @LittleChild: In any language that allows casting bool to int, this would not even be necessary; we could simply use the bool itself...

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by:

> Being new to writing custom Comparators, I am unable to sort them
>   properly.

Anyway, two notices from my point of view:

- both: date1 & date2 are unused, is it desired?
- It seems to me that category variable is a field, right? If yes, then it is a source of your problems. Because `compare` method should not take under consideration any fields, only two compared objects.

And final tip: writing `Comparator` is really trivial task ;) You just need to return integer that is zero, greater than zero, or lesser than zero. That's all.
Please take a look for example at the source code of the `java.lang.Integer.compare()`.

---

EDIT, you can take a look at code below:

```
public class ParseObject implements Comparable<ParseObject>  {

    @Override
    public int compareTo (ParseObject o) {
        String cat1 = this.getString (Fields.CATEGORY);
        String cat2 = o.getString (Fields.CATEGORY);

        return cat1.compareTo (cat2);
    }

    public String getString(Fields field) {
        return "some string"; // TODO
    }
}

enum Fields {
    CATEGORY, EVENT_DATE;
}
```

Comment: So, how do I move the events with a matching category go to the start of the list? One way is to remove them from the list and add them back to the start. This seems more like a hack than an actual solution

Comment: yes, it is a field. However, how do you really compare two objects if not based on some field? :)

Comment: @LittleChild you should compare fields only from two objects, nothing else.

Comment: @LittleChild 
And secondly: `Comparator` should NOT sort anything itself. `Collections.sort()` can for example sort something, in order your comparator will indicate ;)